# Find the last record inserted in SQL which neither id nor date field

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table which has neither id column nor any date and time field, I want to show the last 5 record inserted in the table, I have tried so many things using SP and View but did not find any luck, using magic table I can only finding the last inserted record but I am trapped here for 5 or ten last record pleas help me

table structure

```
Customercode, Journalcode, Invoiec_no, qty, amount
```

Comment: Why can you not just add in an auto_incrementing int into the table?

Comment: Is your Invoice_No field sequential?

Comment: Change the database to suit your needs then. i.e. Add a date field

Answer (score 5):

You can't.

You need to add an increasing column that indicates insert order. SQL Server doesn't maintain this information on your behalf.

Comment: if i add a new field id , i can track the record which would be created after that addition, but before that i have to found last 50 records due to some wrong entry in invoice and that hard copy is missed and total record in the table is more than 100k, so one option i have go manually and find it which one is the last one

Comment: If this is a one off task you might be able to retrieve this information from the transaction log. Can you answer the following questions: Were the last 50 records all inserted since your last full backup?  Do you even do backups? What recovery model is the database in?

Comment: every Friday the backup of database is scheduled and its incremental, i have not much hands on dba side i tried for recovery but it need a third party tool which is not feasible for the scenario

Answer (score 0):

You can't do it you need to have the PK (auto incrementing int) field or date or something in there so you know when records were inserted.

Do you collect the data else where in the system in which case you might be able to do a join through the tables.

Personally from the sounds of it I would just add an extra column and make it either a auto date or auto incrementing field.

Answer (score -1):

This is real dirty way of doing it, but you could do a `select * from table` then take the last 5?

Comment: This won't work. If `ORDER BY` isn't specified SQL Server returns the records in the quickest order possible. This is not neccesarily the order they were entered in.

Comment: thanks Curt - it's not even 9:30am and i've already learnt something new about sql!

Comment: @Curt: I seem to recall that prior to version 7, SQLServer would return unordered records in the order of their first index (I believe MySQL still does this). It's not particularly helpful in this context, since the primary key is not age-related, even if the OP is using an older version of SQLServer.

Comment: @MarkBannister - Yes this is why seanxe has most likely assumed they are ordered by their entry date, as they may be referring to a table which has an indexed PK auto-increment field. If I've understood you correctly?